# NGINX server not responding to new connections intermittently

Tags: nginx, tcp

I have a web server set up and it usually responds extremely fast (<100ms) and on repeated connections even with keepalive_timeout set to 0 has no issues connecting. However, occasionally on connecting to the site the browser will stall forever and Wireshark shows several TCP Retransmission packets that are not responded to. NGINX shows no issues in the access log.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
thread_pool default threads=32 max_queue=65536;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;


events {
        worker_connections 512;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile                        off;
        tcp_nopush                      off;
        tcp_nodelay                     on;
        #keepalive_timeout              10;
        keepalive_timeout               0;
        #types_hash_max_size            2048;

        #client_body_buffer_size        128k;
        client_max_body_size            10G;
        #client_header_buffer_size      1k;
        #large_client_header_buffers    4 4k;
        #output_buffers                 2 32k;
        postpone_output                 0;

        #server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

        access_log                      on;

        log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                                 'rt=$request_time uct="$upstream_connect_time" uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"';

        include                         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type                    application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_certificate                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.baldeonline.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key             /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.baldeonline.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DSS';
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

        resolver 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.baldeonline.com/chain.pem;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log                      /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;
        error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip                            on;
        gzip_disable                    "msie6";
        gzip_min_length 32;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.baldeonline.com :

```
server {
        server_name www.baldeonline.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        ssl    on;
        root "/http/www.baldeonline.com";
        include /etc/nginx/generalSubdomainHandler;
        location /phpmyadmin/ {
                allow 192.168.1.0/24;
                allow 10.8.0.0/24;
                deny all;
        }
        location /phppgadmin/ {
                allow 192.168.1.0/24;
                allow 10.8.0.0/24;
                deny all;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name $host;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: did you get this fixed at all ... from what you describe I have exactly the same issue?

Comment: I bought a new router and it appears to have no issues now. I'm guessing it's not an Nginx issue more a network hardware issue - For reference my old router was a BT Business Hub 5